# HTML5 video in Opera 12.17

Tags: html, angularjs, html5-video, opera

Opera browser version 12.17 . Does this version support MP4 h.264 video playback ? 
Works in FF, IE and chrome , but does not work in Opera.

```
 <div class="row">
       <video id="video" width="50%" height="50%" preload="none"  controls  autoplay>
           <source src="{{videosrc}}" type="video/mp4" />
       </video>
    </div>
```

---

..
server side

```
$scope.videosrc = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(episode.geturl());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opera 12 doesn't support h.264 video natively, so you'll need to fallback to using plugins, e.g flash.

Opera 25 and up supports h.264 if supported by the OS (Note: for linux users - you may need to build ffmpeg if the system libs aren't compatible, see [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/ruario/7b33ca4cf70e6ff70880)).